# Hibernate Java - Unexpected AST Node AND and =

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

I am currently writing a query on Hibernate 5.2.10.Final and keep on encountering Unexpected AST Node error, the query is here

```sql
SELECT
    DISTINCT cs
FROM
    CashbackSetting cs
LEFT JOIN CashbackRegisterSetting crs ON
    cs.id = crs.cashbackSetting.id
LEFT JOIN crs.affiliates af
LEFT JOIN CashbackDepositSetting cds ON
    cs.id = cds.cashbackSetting.id
LEFT JOIN cds.memberGroups mg
LEFT JOIN CashbackPaymentMethod cpm ON
    cds.id = cpm.cashbackDepositSetting.id
LEFT JOIN cpm.banks b
WHERE
    cs.merchant = :merchant
    AND (cs.currency = :currency)
    AND (:id IS NULL
        OR cs.id = :id)
    AND (coalesce(:cashbackTypes) IS NULL
        OR cs.cashbackType IN (:cashbackTypes))
    AND (cs.startDate >= :startDate
        AND cs.endDate <= :endDate)
    AND (:createdBy IS NULL
        OR cs.createdBy = :createdBy)
    AND (:modifiedBy IS NULL
        OR cs.lastModifiedBy = :modifiedBy)
    AND (:status IS NULL
        OR cs.status = :status)
    AND ((CASE
        WHEN (cs.cashbackType = 'REGISTER') THEN ((CASE
            WHEN (:applyType IS NULL) THEN 1
            WHEN (:applyType = 'CODE_LIST') THEN ((CASE
                WHEN (:useAllAffCode IS NOT NULL) THEN (crs.useAll = :useAllAffCode)
                ELSE (:affId IS NULL
                    OR af.id = :affId)
                END) = 1)
            ELSE (crs.affCodeApplyType = :applyType)
            END) = 1) <!-- error in this line '=' -->
        ELSE (((CASE
            WHEN (:useAllPaymentMethods IS NULL OR :useAllPaymentMethods = FALSE) THEN (
                (:paymentMethod IS NULL OR cpm.paymentMethod = :paymentMethod) 
                AND ((CASE
                    WHEN (:useAllChannelId IS NULL
                        OR :useAllChannelId = FALSE) THEN (:channelId IS NULL
                        OR b.id = :channelId)
                    ELSE (cpm.useAll = TRUE)
                    END) = 1))
            ELSE (cds.useAllPaymentMethods = TRUE)
            END) = 1)
            AND ((CASE <!-- error in this line 'AND' -->
                WHEN (:useAllMemberGroups IS NULL
                    OR :useAllMemberGroups = FALSE) THEN (:groupId IS NULL
                    OR mg.id = :groupId)
                ELSE (cds.useAllMemberGroups = TRUE)
                END) = 1))
        END) = 1)
```

the error:

```
2023-11-09 15:27:09.496 ERROR [CashMarket,,,] 23208 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : <AST>:50:25: unexpected AST node: AND
2023-11-09 15:27:09.500 ERROR [CashMarket,,,] 23208 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : <AST>:50:25: unexpected AST node: AND

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: AND
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expressionOrSubQuery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5358)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.elseClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5431)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.searchedCaseExpression(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5267)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.caseExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5127)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.arithmeticExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3355)
```

```
2023-11-09 15:27:07.218  WARN [CashMarket,,,] 23208 --- [onMonitorThread] c.h.s.i.o.impl.InvocationMonitor         : [127.0.0.1]:13782 [dev] [3.7.8] BroadcastOperationHeartbeatsTask delayed 278531 ms
2023-11-09 15:27:07.220 ERROR [CashMarket,,,] 23208 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter        : <AST>:38:30: unexpected AST node: =

antlr.NoViableAltException: unexpected AST node: =
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expressionOrSubQuery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5358)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.searchedCaseWhenClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.searchedCaseExpression(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5251)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.caseExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5127)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.arithmeticExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3355)
```

so, according to the log and function expressionOrSubQuery()'s source, the '=' in line 38 and 'AND in line 50 should not be there, can anyone suggest me a change?

I was expecting it to be able to be built successfully as I was able to run the sql version correctly on workbench. Apparently HQL has many rules under the flow that simply parsing sql with hql format wouldn't cut it.